# Fancybox - Wordpress image caption

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I'm trying to figure out how to open up an image using fancybox, but I need to have a div with some text beside the image. The text that I need to load is the caption of the image, so it isn't an inline text.

Comment: I would like use hardcode, and to not use too many plugins.
I can show you an example of what I should look like here:

http://www.streetammo.dk/

Click the diffrent clothing items below (Quickshop) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at least try first.

To start with, download Fancybox and add to WordPress theme head ( `index.php` or `header.php` , depends on your theme structure ).

Then, call the Fancybox function to add link to popup the Fancybox. The caption can be found by:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type'     => 'attachment', 
    'numberposts'   => -1, 
    'post_status'   => null, 
    'post_parent'   => $post->ID 
); 
// get all attachments
$attachments = get_posts($args);
foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
  $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
  $title = $attachment->post_title;
  // use these information in Fancybox with your logic
}
```